# sp2013 display templates: How to pass variable value to function as parameter?

Tags: display-template

I am trying to programming some logic in sharepoint display templates. The power from these display templates is because you can mix html and javascript.

I see this comments in one of display templates:

```
<!--
        Use the div below to author your Display Template. Here are some things to keep in mind:
        * Surround any JavaScript logic as shown below using a "pound underscore" (#_ ... _#) token
        inside a comment.

        * Use the values assigned to your variables using an "underscore pound equals"
        (_#= ... =#_) token.
    -->
```

I have also some code like this and it works:

```
    <div id="ItemAgenda">
<!--#_

var itemDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "Created");
var itemPicture =  $getItemValue(ctx, "FotoBestuurder");

var introText = $getItemValue(ctx, "IntroText");
introText.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);

var encodedId = $htmlEncode(ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId() + "_introTextId_");
var introTextId = encodedId + "introText";

_#-->
<img id="imgBestuurderFoto"  src="_#=itemPicture=#_" width="200" height="200" onclick="SetDetailInfo('test 123')" style="padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;" />
<div class="cbs-Line2" title="_#= $htmlEncode(introText.defaultValueRenderer(introText)) =#_" id="_#= introTextId =#_" style="display:block;" >_#= introText =#_</div>
</div>
```

In the code you see for example `_#= introText =#_` and it will print the value of variable "introText". Now I would like to add the value of this variable as a parameter to the onclick function:

```
onclick="SetDetailInfo('test 123')"
```

So this is what I want:

```
onclick="SetDetailInfo(_#= introText =#_)"
```

But it doesnt work. Does someone know what I need to do?

Comment: When does the rendered HTML look like for your onclick?  Is that value being populated at all?

Comment: Is it not enough to add ' around the value passed in to the function? As in your working example? SetDetailInfo('_#= introText =#_')

Comment: The differance between yours and mine is that you are using quotes. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: yes this works, thank you Robert Lindgren: SetDetailInfo('#= introText =#')

Comment: Where did you define the function SetDetailInfo(somestring) ?